# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userContext in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, windows-update

I am facing a strange issue that, getting a message as "Value can not be null. Parameter name is userContext" while clicking on Extensions and updates under tools menu.

[image]

Please do let me know what is the workaround for this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I just started seeing this today as well, perhaps after installing a Windows Update.  One of my updates was "2017-06 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB4022714)", among others.

Comment: Filed a issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77580/error-dialog-when-opening-extensions-value-can-not.html

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski My apologies for not mentioning the Windows version. I was getting this error in my office machine which Windows 7.

Comment: have you tried to sign out and sign-in again in Visual Studio? was just getting the same trying to double-click a notification about update 15.4.3 of VS2017 being available (btw, I'm on Win10 Fall Creators Update). It was enough to just close and restart VS2017 community edition to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.  I uninstalled KB4022714 from Start > Windows Update >  Advanced Options > View your Update History. The problem went away, but came back after the next Windows Update.

I had to update Windows 10 to build 14393 to actually fix the problem for good.

Comment: My apologies for not mentioning the Windows version. I was getting this error in my office machine which Windows 7.

Comment: I see. Check if any other Windows updates might be causing it.