# Error message 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userContext' in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I get error message

> 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userContext'

in Visual Studio 2017 when trying to click notification or opening Extensions and updates from tools folder. 
Before answering can you look [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44977569/8225828). The answer did not work on me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem. Close VS,  go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\` and delete/rename a folder whose name starts with `15.0_`.

Then start Visual Studio, then download and install the latest update.

After that it should work - Best of luck.

Comment: you should have mentioned all recent solutions and custom settings would be deleted.  I even lost my color theme extension.

Comment: Solutions are not deleted.  Their link is just removed from the start screen.

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem to. My solution is quite similar from Tahir Hassan.

1. Go to ...AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0...\ **delete** the file `"privateregistry.user.bin"`
2. Start Visual Studio -> VS only ask to sign in or not.

You don't have to download any updates after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2022.  I would perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and it would simply give me a message box saying:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: textView.

Simply closing and reopening Visual Studio worked to resolve this, if anyone is experiencing this issue.