# VS 2017 Debug Mode Cannot See Object Property Values

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I recently updated my Visual Studio 2017 from 15.4.2 to 15.4.5.

At some point during the day I realized that in debug mode I could no longer view objects while stepping through code.  I brought up VS 2015 and that environment still works.

Some things I found online suggested setting certain values in the debug options menu on the visual studtio environment, but that did not help either.

The Image shows there is no expand arrow to view the SomeObject item.

[image]

(visual studio 2017 bug)

This image shows my same machine with Visual Studio 2015 and the expected behavior.  Until recently 2017 had this behavior.
[image: VS2015 showing object properties]

(visual studio 2015 expected behavior)

Comment: Could you share a screen shot about the correct result in your VS2015? Do you mean that you could get all items if you put the mouse on the "new" keywords in your VS 2015? Please share a correct result in your side with a screen shot, so I could really reproduce this issue and compare them with yours clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just test it in VS 2017 15.4.4 and 15.5.0. They all could show all items' value.

Since the latest VS 2017 has been updated to 15.5.0, if possible, please try to use the latest version. Debug it again.

Comment: After updating, then solving the issue many others have posted about here:[usercontext null link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547618/error-message-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-usercontext-in-visual-stud) I have finally got it working.  Thank you for responding.  I'm very concerned about the frequency of obscure bugs with these releases.

Comment: @Adam Heeg, Glad to know that it has been resolved, if so, you could mark the solution as the answer, so it could help other community members, and we could close case for you. In addition,  VS product team collected the feedback though the VS report tool actively, but they really resolved many of the reports with new update packages even if it really has frequent updates in this year. Thanks for you feedback:)

Comment: I have got the same problem in 15.5.2 and it is driving me crazy. I've reset all settings and deleted the file as suggested above and still I have no properties showing whilst hovering over objects when stepping through in debug. Any other ideas?